# Redirect from within controller always goes to home page

Tags: 8, redirection, page-controller

I have a custom module named `rsc`.

My `Default 404 (not found) page` is set to `/page-not-found` in `Basic site settings`.

My rsc.routing.yml file contains

```
  rsc.pageNotFound:
    path: '/page-not-found'
    defaults:
      _controller: 'Drupal\rsc\Controller\rscController::pageNotFound'
      _title: ''
    requirements:
      _permission: 'access content'
```

My rscController.php file contains:

```
  class rscController extends ControllerBase
  {
    public function pageNotFound()
    {
      $path = '/test-page'; // Just for testing

      if (($url = \Drupal::service('path.validator')->getUrlIfValid($path))) {
        $route = $url->getRouteName();
        $param = $url->getRouteParameters();
        error_log("route=$route param=" . print_r($param, true));
        return $this->redirect($route, $param);
      }
      else {
        return
        [
          '#markup' => 'No such page'
        ];
      }
    }
  }
```

`/test-page` is the alias for `/node/125`.

If I type `mywebsite.com/junk` in the address bar (to force the not found page to be invoked) and press Enter, I am always redirected to the home page, even though the error log contains the result

route=entity.node.canonical param=Array
  (
    [node] => 125
  )

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't $this->redirect() take me to the node?

Comment: Did you check the network responses in chromes (or firefox) Dev Tools? Maybe there's another redirect for any reason.

Comment: When you call a controller as error page via the basic site settings this is not the controller of the main request, this controller is executed in a subrequest to get a themed output of the otherwise simple text message. Better place the redirect in the main request, for example in an exception subscriber. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/245211/47547

Comment: Another good example to copy from is the redirect_404 submodule of the https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect module. It uses the approach described by @4k4

Comment: After following the suggestion from 4k4 above, I got this working. I have posted my working code at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/290447/where-and-how-to-conditionally-redirect-old-aliases-to-new-aliases/290659#290659 because the question there is broader and takes in more of the solution. @4k4, if you'll post your suggestion as an answer, I'll accept it so people will see this has an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a controller as error page via the basic site settings this is not the controller of the main request, this controller is executed in a subrequest to get a themed output of the otherwise simple text message you see for non 4xx exceptions like a 500 error.

Better place the redirect in the main request, before the rendering of the exception is delegated to a subrequest by [CustomPageExceptionHtmlSubscriber](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21EventSubscriber%21CustomPageExceptionHtmlSubscriber.php/class/CustomPageExceptionHtmlSubscriber/8.8.x). You can use the default priority 0, because the core exception handler has -50.

@MarshallMorrise has posted the working code at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/290659/47547